# How to extract array's element from column of arrays?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one of the columns consist of arrays. I need to extract first element from each array in this column. So, for the first row it would be 'classical harp', for 2nd - 'classic persian pop' etc. Here is an example:

[image]

And my code below. I tried using lambda along with `apply` or `assign` but it doesn't work - I mean I can't take first element of each array in a column:

```
df = df.assign(top_genre = lambda x: x['genres'][0])
df['new'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

How to amend my code to make it work properly?

Comment: `df['new'] = df['genres'].str[0]`

Comment: can I use lambda in this case? if so what's wrong with my code?

Comment: hard to debug your code with an image as input, you must provide a reproducible input

Comment: I tried it with my dataset (`genres` column): https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lehaknarnauli/spotify-datasets?select=artists.csv. However, I got error. Don't know how to overcome it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with lambda u can use

```
df['new'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
```

Comment: it doesn't work with my dataset, it's publicly available: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lehaknarnauli/spotify-datasets?select=artists.csv. I can't retrieve first element from 'genres' column. I tried your code and get `'str' object has no attribute 'str'` error. I also tried this: `df['new'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: '[]' if not x else x[0])` - unfortunately I got `[` as an outcome. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: can your print  df['genres'] to see because it work for me